# php-fpm process dieing

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a problem. Playing around with php-fpm and nginx yields great results for speed. However the php-fpm process just dies if I hold F5 for like, 10 seconds.

Is there a way to prevent the php-fpm process to die like that? Can't it just "wait" or reject the overflow rather than turn off?

Cheers,